# Canonical outer join zip function

Tags: haskell, zip, outer-join

If you consider the (implicit) indexes of each element of a list as their keys, then `zipWith` is sort of like a relational inner join.  It only processes the keys for which both inputs have values:

```
zipWith (+) [1..5] [10..20] == zipWith (+) [1..11] [10..14] == [11,13,15,17,19]
```

Is there a canonical corresponding function corresponding to outer join?  Something like:

```
outerZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
outerZipWith _ _ _ [] [] = []
outerZipWith f a' b' [] (b:bs) = f a' b : outerZipWith f a' b' [] bs
outerZipWith f a' b' (a:as) [] = f a b' : outerZipWith f a' b' as []
outerZipWith f a' b' (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : outerZipWith f a' b' as bs
```

or maybe

```
outerZipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
outerZipWith' _ _ _ [] [] = []
outerZipWith' _ Nothing _ [] _ = []
outerZipWith' _ _ Nothing _ [] = []
outerZipWith' f a' b' [] (b:bs) = f (fromJust a') b : outerZipWith f a' b' [] bs
outerZipWith' f a' b' (a:as) [] = f a (fromJust b') : outerZipWith f a' b' as []
outerZipWith' f a' b' (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : outerZipWith f a' b' as bs
```

So I can do

```
outerZipWith (+) 0 0 [1..5] [10..20]  == [11,13,15,17,19,15,16,17,18,19,20]
outerZipWith (+) 0 0 [1..11] [10..14] == [11,13,15,17,19,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I find myself needing it from time to time, and I'd rather use a common idiom to make my code more writable (and easier to maintain) rather than implementing `outerZipWith`, or doing `if length as < length bs then zipWith f (as ++ repeat a) bs else zipWith f as (bs ++ repeat b)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems awkward because you're trying to skip to the end rather than deal with the primitive operations.

First of all, `zipWith` is conceptually a `zip` followed by `map (uncurry ($))`. This is an important point, because (un)currying is why `zipWith` is possible at all. Given lists with types `[a]` and `[b]`, to apply a function `(a -> b -> c)` and get something of type `[c]` you obviously need one of each input. The two ways to do this are precisely the two `Applicative` instances for lists, and `zipWith` is `liftA2` for one of them. (The other instance is the standard one, which gives the cartesian product--a cross join, if you prefer).

The semantics you want don't correspond to any obvious `Applicative` instance, which is why it's much more difficult. Consider first an `outerZip :: [a] -> [b] -> [?? a b]` and what type it would have. The elements of the result list could each be an `a`, `b`, or both. This not only doesn't correspond to any standard data type, it's awkward to express in terms of them because you can't factor anything useful out of the expression `(A + B + A*B)`.

Such a data type has its own uses, which is why I have [my own package defining one](https://github.com/isomorphism/these). I recall there being one on hackage as well (with fewer auxiliary functions than mine, I think) but I can't remember what it was called.

Sticking to just standard stuff, you end up needing a sensible "default value" which roughly translates into having a `Monoid` instance and using the identity value to pad the lists out. Translating to and from an appropriate `Monoid` using `newtype` wrappers or such may not end up being any simpler than your current implementation, however.

---

As an aside, your remark about list indices as keys can actually be developed further; any `Functor` with a similar notion of a key is isomorphic to the `Reader` monad, a.k.a. an explicit function from keys to values. Edward Kmett has, as always, a bunch of packages encoding these abstract notions, in this case building from [the `representable-functors` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors). Might be helpful, if you don't mind writing a dozen instances just to get started at least...

Comment: Wouldn't `outerZip :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`?

Comment: More like `outerZip :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> c -> d -> [a] -> [b] -> [(c, d)]`

Comment: An inclusive-or type (like your `These`) may be the necessary first step.  At the very least, it's a good place to start.

Comment: `outerZip f a b as bs = map (f . fromThese a b) $ zipThese as bs` is very clean.  I like it.

Comment: Also, in terms of factoring, given `These`, we now have two representations for `a + b + a*b + 1`: `Maybe (These a b)`, `(Maybe a, Maybe b)`.

Comment: @pat: Not necessarily. It could, depending on your choice of how to handle the "past the end of one list" cases. You need to express the output as an explicitly inclusive or for full generality, or supply equivalent injection/projection functions that serve the same purpose.

Comment: @rampion: Only the latter is really a factorization, in the sense of having a unique "slot" for each type argument. `These` just gives a name to a specific, fairly simple expression that doesn't factor.

Comment: @Apocalisp: That type signature is arguably still too inclusive, though, as it doesn't clearly exclude generating extra pairs using the `c` and `d` arguments. With `zip` the type clearly shows that the only results present will be pairs made from elements found in the inputs.

Comment: @rampion: Oh, also--since collecting inputs like this as an intermediate step is the obvious use for a type like `These`, I tried to be very comprehensive with projections, case analysis functions, and predicates for `These`, specifically to support cleanly defining things like your `outerZip`. :]

Answer (score 8):

This kind of thing comes up a lot. It's the `cogroup` operation of the [PACT algebra](http://www.redaktion.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg131/Publikation/Papers/ComparingMapReduceAndPACTs.pdf). Where I work, we make use of type classes to differentiate these three operations:

1. `zip`: Structural intersection.
2. `align`: Structural union.
3. `liftA2`: Structural cartesian product.

This is discussed by [Paul Chiusano on his blog](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2010/06/alignable-functors-typeclass-for-zippy.html).

Comment: That Paul Chiusano blog entry is straightforward and insightful.  Thanks for linking that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of filling out the shorter list with a constant, why not provide a list of values to take until the end of the longer list is reached?  This also eliminates the need for a `Maybe`   since the list can be empty (or of finite length).

I couldn't find anything standard, but short of a complete re-implementation of `zipWith` along the lines you showed, I developed your `length` test version like this:

```
outerZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
outerZipWith f as bs as' bs' = take n $ zipWith f (as ++ as') (bs ++ bs')
  where n = max (length as) (length bs)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (for me at least).