# Outerzip / zip longest function (with multiple fill values)

Tags: python

Is there a Python function an "outer-zip", which is a extension of [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) with  different default values for each iterable?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]   # associate a default value 0
b = [4, 5, 6, 7] # associate b default value 1

zip(a,b)  # [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

outerzip((a, 0), (b, 1)) = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (0, 7)]
outerzip((b, 0), (a, 1)) = [(4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 1)]
```

I can almost replicate this outerzip function using [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), but with `None` as the *only* default:

```
map(None, a, b) # [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (None, 7)]
```

*Note1: The built-in [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function takes an arbitrary number of iterables, and so should an `outerzip` function. (e.g. one should be able to calculate `outerzip((a,0),(a,0),(b,1))` similarly to `zip(a,a,b)` and `map(None, a, a, b)`.)*

*Note2: I say "outer-zip", in the style of [this haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198410/canonical-outer-join-zip-function), but perhaps this is not correct terminology.*

Comment: should one be able to calculate `outerzip(a,0,a,2,b,1)`?

Comment: That's a good question! I'm not sure whether this would make sense (personally it doesn't happen for me since a list's elements are always of a particular type and so have an implicit default value), but I'm not sure in a general `outerzip` function...

Comment: useful trick with `map`.

Comment: IMHO your question would be better titled something like "zip_longest() with multiple fill-values?" since it's tagged "Python".

Comment: @martineau re-titled, kept both (though I guess zip_longest is a more pythonic name!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [modify `zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to support your use case for general iterables.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

class OuterZipStopIteration(Exception):
    pass

def outer_zip(*args):
    count = len(args) - 1

    def sentinel(default):
        nonlocal count
        if not count:
            raise OuterZipStopIteration
        count -= 1
        yield default

    iters = [chain(p, sentinel(default), repeat(default)) for p, default in args]
    try:
        while iters:
            yield tuple(map(next, iters))
    except OuterZipStopIteration:
        pass


print(list(outer_zip( ("abcd", '!'), 
                      ("ef", '@'), 
                      (map(int, '345'), '$') )))
```

Comment: Your use of `nonlocal` makes this a Python 3-only solution -- although a Python 2.x version could probably also easily be written.

Comment: @martineau: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706/nonlocal-keyword-in-python-2-x for how to substitute `nonlocal` in Python 2.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware there are workarounds. As a matter of fact in the [2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=izip_longest#itertools.izip_longest) for `izip_longest()` one is used for the `counter` variable in the pure Python code it says is equivalent -- which is why I said creating a 2.x version would probably be a relatively easy thing to do. I made my comment because the OP's question is not tagged Python-3.x.

Comment: This function is/was *very* clever, and deserves a bounty! One little question looking back, was there a reason to call the sub-function "sentinel"?

Comment: @AndyHayden: Probably to convey that it's a "sentinel value".

Comment: @KennyTM ooooh... it seems I did not know the precise meaning of that word! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 13):

It's called [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) ([`zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in python-3.x):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> list(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (0, 7)]
```

Comment: Can I have a different fill value for a and for b?

Comment: @hayden: how would that work? call `zip_longest` w/ two different `fillvalue`s depending on the length of `a` and `b`.

Comment: You could do `fill = A if len(a)<len(b) else B` then call `list(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=fill))`

Comment: `list(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=1 if len(a)>len(b) else 0))`

Comment: @hayden: if that was essential to your question then it needs to be posted in the body of the question. Or in another question. As it stands, your original question is answered.

Comment: I asked if there was a general outerzip function, I should have made it clearer that I wanted it to work generally, having different default values is already in the question... but I'll update]

Comment: Your answer is inconsistent in that it uses both `zip_longest()` and `izip_longest()`...

Answer (score 3):

This function can be defined by extending each inputted list and zipping:

```
def outerzip(*args):
    # args = (a, default_a), (b, default_b), ...
    max_length = max( map( lambda s: len(s[0]), args))
    extended_args = [ s[0] + [s[1]]*(max_length-len(s[0])) for s in args ]
    return zip(*extended_args)

outerzip((a, 0), (b, 1)) # [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (0, 7)]
```